# Multiple systems of equations questions on one line

Tags: cases

I am trying to write two simultaneous equation questions on the same line - like you would find in a maths textbook.

For general questions I have been using environment `tabenum` which puts 2 or more questions on one line nicely.
However when I try to use environment `cases` within this item listing, it does not seem to work. Is it somehow conflicting with `tabenum`?

Here's what I have at the moment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tablists}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabenum}
\tabenumitem
Question 1 here \hspace{3cm}
\tabenumitem
$\begin{cases} 2x-3y=-5\\5x+4y=22 \end{cases}$
\end{tabenum}
\end{document}
```

And here is the error that appears:

```
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning preamble of \halign.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix/change this? Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Thank you! Also, thank you for the edits - I am not familiar with the correct formatting, so I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tasks` package is done for that. The argument in parentheses of the environment is the number of columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=tsk[1].}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task
Question 1 here

\task
$\begin{cases} 2x-3y=-5\\5x+4y=22 \end{cases}$
\task Another question

\task A last question
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems much simpler to use than tablists, especially with spacing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Putting the math with environment `cases` inside a box helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tablists}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabenum}
\tabenumitem
Question 1 here \hspace{3cm}
\tabenumitem
\mbox{$\begin{cases} 2x-3y=-5\\5x+4y=22 \end{cases}$}
\end{tabenum}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]